# How do I include a maven package that has invalid/outdated POM?

Tags: java, maven

I want to use a package named [`sourcemap`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.sourcemap/sourcemap) in my project. It's not available in maven central, but in [Atlassian's public maven repository](https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/). I therefore set up my `pom.xml` like this:

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>atlassian</id>
            <name>Atlassian</name>
            <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sourcemap</groupId>
            <artifactId>sourcemap</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now, the POM file for `sourcemap` references another POM file from a package named `public-pom`:

```xml
    <!-- POM for sourcemap (NOT my pom.xml!) -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.pom</groupId>
        <artifactId>public-pom</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.84</version>
    </parent>
```

The problem: the POM file references version 3.0.84 of `public-pom`, but Atlassian's repo no longer provides 3.0.84. Currently, the oldest available version of `public-pom` is 5.0.0, as you can see [here](https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/com/atlassian/pom/public-pom/). Because of this, maven complains when I attempt to build the project:

```
Could not find artifact com.atlassian.pom:public-pom:pom:3.0.84 in atlassian (https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/)
```

How can I fix the POM and use this package in my project?

Comment: You have to use a more recent version. No other solution...

Comment: @khmarbaise This is the latest version of `sourcemap`. Can I modify the POM of `sourcemap` to point to a recent version of `public-pom`?

Answer (score 0):

Mvnrepository [lists](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.pom/public-pom?repo=atlassian-public) [`com.atlassian.pom:public-pom:pom:3.0.84`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.pom/public-pom/3.0.84) but when selecting [the link to it](https://packages.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-public/com/atlassian/pom/public-pom/3.0.84/public-pom-3.0.84.pom):

```json
status:     404
message:    "Could not find resource"
```

Comment: I think it might work if I could somehow fix the POM of `sourcemap` to point to a recent version of `public-pom`. But how do I modify the POM of a dependency that I don't own?

Comment: @PhilKang Dependencies are JARs. JARs are ZIPs. Extract/view it, there's a folder `/META-INF/maven/` in it.

Comment: So I can just extract the JAR contents, edit the POM, zip it and name it JAR and it just works?

Comment: @PhilKang I cannot give any guarantee since I never did this yet but that's what I would try next. And hopefully the code in the JAR is compatible with the new version you enter and use then.